# How to handle the ORA-00972: identifier is too long Exception with Hibernate 5 a Naming Strategy

Tags: database, oracle, hibernate, jdbc, orm

So I recently hit this error with Oracle and Hibernate:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00972: identifier is too long
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
```

and after some google-ing I came to these projects:

https://github.com/schauder/hibernate-naming-strategy-for-oracle (almost 9 years old)
https://code.google.com/archive/p/hibernate-naming-strategy-for-oracle/ (not maintained any more)

however none of these work with Hibernate5. In Hibernate5 there has been 2 new naming strategies - a physical and implicit one. Does any of you know if there is a hibernate5 naming strategy to overcome the oracle's 30 characters limit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you can customize the way Hibernate 5 maps the physical naming strategy. For instance, you can write the following `PhysicalNamingStartegy`:

```
public class OracleNamingStrategy extends PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl {

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalColumnName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment context) {
        Identifier original = super.toPhysicalColumnName(name, context);
        if(original.getText().length() > 30) {
            return Identifier.toIdentifier(original.getText().substring(0, 30), original.isQuoted());
        }
        return original;
    }
}
```

And provide this naming strategy as a configuration property:

```
properties.put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", "com.vladmihalcea.book.hpjp.hibernate.naming.OracleNamingStrategy");
```

Considering the following entity mapping:

```
@Entity(name = "Person")
public static class Person  {

    @Id
    private Long personId;

    @ManyToOne
    private PersonAddress addressIsAVeryLongColumnThatExceedsThirtyCharacters;

    @ManyToOne
    private PersonLocation location;
}
```

Hibernate will just truncate the column size like this:

```
create table Person (personId number(19,0) not null, addressIsAVeryLongColumnThatEx number(19,0), location_id number(19,0), primary key (personId))
```

Code available on [GitHub](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/high-performance-java-persistence/tree/master/core/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/book/hpjp/hibernate/naming).

Comment: I don't think this works for `@CollectionTable`. I have the following declaration:
````
    @CollectionTable(name = ("classification_attribute_name_lv"), joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = ("classification_attribute_pk"))
    }, indexes = {
        @Index(name = (("idx_"+ "classification_attribute_name_lv"), columnList = ("classification_attribute_pk"))
    }, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = (("fk_"+ "classification_attribute_name_lv")))
````

Comment: It works for basic types. For `@CollectionTable`, you need to provide a `hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy` configuration property which designates your custom implementation of `ImplicitNamingStrategy`. The custom implementation must overwrite `determineCollectionTableName`.

Comment: Actually method `toPhysicalTableName` seems to be enough. Unfortunately I have also specified long index names there too:
        @CollectionTable(name = "classification_attribute_name_lv", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "classification_attribute_pk"), indexes = {
                    @Index(name = "idx_classification_attribute_name_lv", columnList = "classification_attribute_pk") }

and this `@Index(name=` cannot be trimmed with neither `Implicit` nor `PhysicalNaming` strategies :(

Comment: Same with the foreign keys: `@ForeignKey(name = "fk_" + NAME + "_delivery_address")`. Once you define a `name=` you can't use a strategy to shrink it. So in my case I have more than 200 entities and ever since I was using mysql but now the customer wants Oracle so I'm stuck :(